# TCP client fails to bind to port 0 in socket using framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, bind

I have a running application that uses Socket communication to connect to a server on some port. I have ported that application from framework 2.0 (Visual Studio) up to framework 4.5 going through all intermediate frameworks with no problem.

Now, with visual studio 15 and framework 4.6.1, the socket no longer connects.
Searching into the code, I found out that the problem was socket.Bind which was throwing an exception when local port is 0. It is worth noting that usually there is no need to bind your local port, but when you have multiple network adapters, and the server allows only for one of your IPs to connect, you need to bind the adapter (or IP) that the socket has to use to initiate its connection, otherwise, the socket will either use a random IP or the one on the top.
Commenting the 'Bind' will work fine, but we lose the ability to specify other local IPs for connecting. Sadly, my IP is not the one selected by default, so I am not longer able to connect in framework 4.6.1

Can anyone help with a solution for this?

```
// IPEndPoint is the local IP to use for connection. Port 0 means random port
IPEndPoint localHost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("123.xxx.xxx.126"), 0);

// now we bind to force the socket to use the provided IP in IPEndPoint
_socket.Bind(localHost);

// Finally, we connect to the server using the bound IP and Port (random)
_socket.Connect("123.xxx.xxx.130",8080);

_socket.Bind will throw the following error (only in fw 4.6.1)
```

> {"The requested address is not valid in its context"}
>       Native Error Code: 10049

And of course, not much help on error 10049 on sockets when used as client.

Comment: Are you sure that the IP address for the local endpoint is valid?  Is it t he port you are concerned with or the IP?  Does it happen to work if you bind to a fixed port number instead of random?

Comment: The IP is valid. I am using the same code on the same client, only the framework has changed.
**Is it t he port you are concerned with or the IP?** I cannot tell, the socket.Bind is failing whenever I call it.
**Does it happen to work if you bind to a fixed port number instead of random?** No, all calls to bind are generating an error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
IPEndPoint localHost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("123.xxx.xxx.126"), 0);
```

With

```
IPEndPoint localHost = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
```

Comment: As I noted before, using 'IPAddress.Any' from a client side connection means select 'Any' IP to use for connection, but does not let you specify which exact LOCAL IP to use for the connection. If you have many LOCAL IPs (multi-homed) and only 1 is white-listed to some external server, then you will be forced to bind the white-listed IP using 'socket.Bind' which will generate an exception in framework 4.6.1.
The generated exception is not from the specified IP but from specifying port 0 I presume.